# Error - Subject expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following migration:

```
    create_table :flows do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :subject, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
```

My Schemas:

```
create_table "flows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.index ["subject_id"], name: "index_flows_on_subject_id"
end
create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
end
```

And on my form I have the select html:

```
<%= f.select :subject, Subject.all.collect {|s| [ s.subject, s.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select subject'}, class:"form-control" %>
```

But it shows the error: Subject(#30363600) expected, got String(#16228440)

```
# POST /flows.json
  def create
    @flow = Flow.new(flow_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @flow.save
```

**Parameters:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"y3cTmsdqweqioXtsCpSlNtmTonyXev+67emGwqfgvGJK4D3Szt1FbZcxe6M7QU8cLYPEbanmkYngzyDvbFPw==",
 "flow"=>{"name"=>"Create Project", "subject"=>"11"},
 "button"=>""}
```

Comment: Can you post your `subjects` table schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a column named as `subject_id`, so try this:

```
<%= f.select :subject_id, Subject.all.collect {|s| [ s.subject, s.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select subject'}, class:"form-control" %>
```

Strong Param should look as follows:

```
def flow_params
 params.require(:flow).permit(:name, :subject_id)
end
```

Comment: I tried, but it appears the following error: **Subject should exist**

Comment: `def flow_params
      params.require(:flow).permit(:name, :subject)
end`

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares check the updated answer and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @dpk  I changed my strong param and my f.select to subject_id, 
but now shows the error: **Subject should exist**. 
When I make _subject_ in my strong and f.select It is shown the error: **Subject expected, got String**

Comment: I changed my migration to **t.integer subject_id** and it worked. Thank you